# Maximum user sessions not working when user signs in Springboot/Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to add maximum sessions to my spring security context, however the settings are not taking effect. I've been following this code to implement JWT tokens on a spring backend using [this tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-1/).

I've added the relevant code I believe to the security config:

```
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/configuration/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and().sessionManagement()
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

However when I try and login with a user - the user can login however many times they wish.

I tried looking in the user registry to see if there were multiple user principles being created for each login but there isn't.

I also tried to step through ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication however that doesn't seem to be being called - but I have no idea why.

Edit:

Adding the customer AuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AuthController.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The session is setting set correctly in the session registry now. However because my login endpoint has permitAll() (I think)

ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication() is not being called and adding the newly created session to the registry.

I believe it might be something to do with the way my CustomAuthenticationProvider is setup:

```
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
```

So signin is always allowing new logins as ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication() is not being called after authentication.

Comment: Can you share your custom AuthenticationEntryPoint?

Comment: Sure - I've added it. Thanks dude.

Comment: How are users able to log in if your AuthenticationEntryPoint always sends an error?

Comment: As far as I know that's only for exceptionHandling()